# AS3: Prevent event from happening twice?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, movieclip

In my game, if the ball hits the winBox, you get a Win message. The problem is that the ball bounces, and it might hit the box repeatedly. How can I prevent the message from happening twice per session?

```
            if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox,gameBall))
        {
            // Won.
            trace ('You won!');
            isFiring=false;

            //Win Message
            winMsg=new win_mc();
            addChild(winMsg);
            winMsg.y=250;
            winMsg.x=40;
            winMsg.gotoAndPlay(2);

        }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

[SWF(width = 300, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

public class LuckyHitBeta extends MovieClip {

    public var sim:QuickBox2D;
    var winBox:QuickObject;
    var looseBox:QuickObject;
    var looseBox2:QuickObject;
    var gameBall:QuickObject;
    var simContacts:QuickContacts;
    var isFiring:Boolean=false;
    var ballIcon:ballIcon_mc;
    var winMsg:win_mc;



    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function LuckyHitBeta()
    {   
        liveIcon();
        sim = new QuickBox2D(this);
        simContacts = sim.addContactListener();
        simContacts.addEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener);
        //Important Collisions;

        winBox = sim.addBox({x:2,y:597/30, width:98/30, height:10/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false});
        looseBox = sim.addBox({x:5,y:597/30, width:98/30, height:10/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false});
        looseBox2 = sim.addBox({x:8,y:597/30, width:98/30, height:10/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false});
        //Collisions
        sim.addBox({x:3.5,y:560/30, width:72/30, height:13/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});
        sim.addBox({x:6.5,y:560/30, width:72/30, height:13/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});
        sim.addBox({x:0/30,y:300/30, width:600/30, height:28/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});
        sim.addBox({x:300/30,y:300/30, width:600/30, height:28/30, density:0, skin:stick, skinScale:false, angle:1.57});



        // make obstacles 
        for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth/28); i++){ 
        //End
             sim.addCircle({x:1.2 + i * 0.8, y:16, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
             sim.addCircle({x:0.6 + i * 0.8, y:15, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
        }

        for (var o:int = 0; o<(stage.stageWidth/55); o++){  
        //Middle

              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:14, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:13, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:12, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:11, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
              sim.addCircle({x:1.3 + o * 1.5, y:10, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
        }

        for (var u:int = 0; u<(stage.stageWidth/45); u++){    
        //Start
             sim.addCircle({x:0.8 + u * 1.3, y:09, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
             sim.addCircle({x:1.55 + u * 1.3, y:08, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
             sim.addCircle({x:0.8 + u * 1.3, y:07, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});
             sim.addCircle({x:1.55 + u * 1.3, y:06, radius:0.15, density:0, skin:ping, scaleSkin:false});

        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
        sim.start();



    }

    /**
     * ..
     * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
     */
     private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
     {  
        if (! isFiring){
            gameBall = sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(2), radius:0.15, density:1, restitution:0.7, friction:0, skin:ball, scaleSkin:false, angularDamping:20});
            isFiring=true;
            ballIcon.gotoAndStop(2);

        }  
     }

    private function liveIcon():void {
        ballIcon=new ballIcon_mc();
        addChild(ballIcon);
        ballIcon.y=30;
    }        

     private function onEnterFrm(e:Event):void
     {          
        ballIcon.x=mouseX;
        if (gameBall && gameBall.body.IsSleeping())
            {
                gameBall.destroy();
                gameBall = null;
                isFiring=false;
                ballIcon.gotoAndStop(1);
            }  
    }

    private function contactListener(e:Event)
    {
        if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox,gameBall))
        {
            // Won.
            trace ('You won!');
            isFiring=false;
            ballIcon.gotoAndStop(1);

            winMsg=new win_mc();
            addChild(winMsg);
            winMsg.y=250;
            winMsg.x=40;
            winMsg.gotoAndPlay(2);

        }

        if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(looseBox,gameBall))
        {
            // Loose.
            trace ('You loose!');
            //gameBall({friction:1,restitution:0});
            isFiring=false;
            ballIcon.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the "You win!" message fire once per ball, remove the event listener when the player wins, and add it each time the user creates a ball. It's ok to add an event listener to the same object multiple times; the event listener function will still only get called once.

```
private function clicked(e:MouseEvent)
{  
    if (!isFiring)
    {
        // Add the ball.
        simContacts.addEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener);
    }
}

...

private function contactListener(e:Event):void
{
    if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox, gameBall))
    {
        // You win.
        simContacts.removeEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener);
    }
    else if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox, gameBall))
    {
        // You lose.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that if I hit the target again, there will be no message!

Comment: Isn't that the goal? You stated, "prevent the message from happening twice per session." What is a session, and when/how does it reset?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well, I use the isFiring = true or false, if is  not firing then it should not allow the message to appear.

Comment: Try the updated example, I think it will work for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could check to see if winMsg has been added. (to whatever you're adding it to. In this example the stage).

```
if (stage.contains(winMsg)) 
{
winMsg=new win_mc();
addChild(winMsg);
winMsg.y=250;
winMsg.x=40;
winMsg.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

So winMsg will only ben added once.

Then remove the winMsg and set it to null when you're done with it.

```
removeChild(winMsg);
winMsg = null;
```

PS. When setting event listeners it's good practice (IMO) to always use weak references, otherwise you might run into problems clearing objects from memory. To do this simply add

,false, 0, true

to the end of your addEventListeners. e.g.

simContacts.addEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener,false, 0, true);